# Error for install AFNetworking ~> 2.2.0 pod

Tags: ios, iphone, github, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have previous version of AFNetworking pod

> pod 'AFNetworking', '1.3.1'

When I run the **$ pod install**

I get following error

> [!] Invalid `AFNetworking.podspec` file: undefined method `social_media_url=' for #. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
>    #  from /Users/Glam/.cocoapods/repos/master/AFNetworking/2.2.0/AFNetworking.podspec:7
>
> - #  -------------------------------------------
> - #    s.homepage = 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking'
> - >    s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/AFNetworking'
> - #    s.authors  = { 'Mattt Thompson' => 'm@mattt.me' }
> - #  -------------------------------------------

what is this s.social_media_url?

Comment: I have followed steps to solve the problem using  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1854

Answer (score 0):

Probably your pod setup are corrupted.

Try this:

```
$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$ pod setup
```

For more information: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/

Answer (score 0):

This exception is because you have an older version of activesupport which isn't compatible with CocoaPods. To install a newer version you could try:

```
gem install activesupport -v 3.2.14
```

And then do your normal pod install.